# Convert slideup,slidedown and appendTo jquery method to javascript method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert some jquery code to javascript code, I converted many lines but I don't know how to convert slideup, slidedown and appendTo to pure javascript.

jquery

```
$('#recentpostbreaking li:first').slideUp( function () { $(this).appendTo($('#recentpostbreaking ul')).slideDown(); });
```

I get some idea from the below url but no use
https://gist.github.com/ludder/4226288

```
function slideDown(elem) {
    elem.style.maxHeight = '1000px';
    // We're using a timer to set opacity = 0 because setting max-height = 0 doesn't (completely) hide the element.
    elem.style.opacity   = '1';
}

/**
 * Slide element up (like jQuery's slideUp)
 * @param  {Node} elem Element
 * @return {[type]}      [description]
 */
function slideUp(elem) {
    elem.style.maxHeight = '0';
    once( 1, function () {
        elem.style.opacity = '0';
    });
}
```

Comment: If your goal is to get rid of jQuery completely, then I suggest to use CSS transitions for slideUp / slideDown. And have a look at the JavaScript appendChild function. 
`parentElement.appendChild(element)`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try.